# what do i need to print from ipad/iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, macos, printing

I want my ipad/iphone app to print to a thermal printer (pos printer). It seems there is no airport express compatible thermal printer in the market. I am not sure if I could use a Mac or Windows as a printer server?

If so: 
1. What kind of configuration do I need to do on iPad & Mac? 
2. Do I need special software on iPad or Mac/Windows?
3. Could any USB thermal printer do the job?

Thanks in advance

Leo

Comment: This question is off-topic, but you might take a look at AirPrint Activator: http://netputing.com/airprintactivator/

Comment: Place it face down on a photocopier?

Comment: Thanks guys! even @PurplePilot, who gave me quite some laugh. Why don't you *answer* my post and I can contribute some rep? By the way, is it possible to print to a Windows shared printer? That's a much cheaper solution in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use the Airport facility provided by apple in their iOS 4.2 release...
[Please go through this link.. this might be of some help....](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-4_2/_index.html)
This is fairly new to iOS and i really wish you would implement this.
[You can also see this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).
Hope this helps at least to some extent.

Answer (score 1):

Place it face down on a photocopier? It sounds dumb in in the first weeks of the iPad if i needed a copy of the screen that is what i did. I mean it's a solution. Not brilliant but ....

Comment: if you really need a "screenshot", you can press Home & Power at the same time.

Comment: @purplepoint: Leo was absolutely right... it is easier to take a screenshot than to do what you mentioned in your answer.. Like you said it's really really dumb